# Two projects reference same package but in different version creating runtime problem

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, nuget-package

I'm trying to solve problem of two projects that try to use same package (`Microsoft.Graph`) but each uses different version of it. (See diagram below).
Orchestrator is an Azure Function that references two Azure Functions from separate projects (`Foo` and `Bar`).
Foo references `PnP.Framework` that references old version of `Microsoft.Graph` (`3.33.0`) and as it is, was working fine until I have added Bar. Bar references newest version of `Microsoft.Graph`  (`5.11.0`).

[image]

After adding `Bar`, `Foo` started to throw following exception:

```
(...)
Result: Function 'FooFunction', Invocation id 'd06cc6ff-1805-4886-808d-f2595db3a30e': An exception was thrown by the invocation.
Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Could not load type 'Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider' from assembly 'Microsoft.Graph.Core, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
Could not load type 'Microsoft.Graph.Group' from assembly 'Microsoft.Graph, Version=5.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
Could not load type 'Microsoft.Graph.IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage' from assembly 'Microsoft.Graph, Version=5.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
Could not load type 'Microsoft.Graph.IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage' from assembly 'Microsoft.Graph, Version=5.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
Could not load type ... etc etc
(...)
```

This shows that `Foo` started to look for `3.33` types in `5.11` version of `Microsoft.Graph` and sure enough, in the bin folder you will only find `Microsoft.Graph.dll` with version `5.11`.

Right now the Orchestrator is calling the Functions in following way

```cs
await context.CallActivityAsync(nameof(FooFunction), coolData);
await context.CallActivityAsync(nameof(BarFunction), coolData);
```

Originally the `FooFunction` and `BarFunction` were placed in the same project. I separated them in hope of possibly isolating dll's to no avail.

I've seen some posts like [this](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-Sites-Core/issues/2548) [or this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-core/issues/629) [and this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1854).

But all of them are workarounds revolving around either dropping or downgrading one of the dependencies or even ...

```
My current workaround is to use a completely different function app for SharePointPnPCoreOnline which is based on .NET framework while all of the Graph and other functionality lives in a different function app based on .NET Core. Any communication between the function apps is done through queue messages. Not ideal but works for the time being.
```

Yeah ... no.

[Microsoft reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution#cousin-dependencies) contains some information about similar scenario but I can't find applicable solution to my case.

Comment: I have the same problem - the PnP guys still did not upgrade their NuGet to a later version of Graph, so I am forced to use the very old version... Any solution yet?